# Onde fica o arquivo: Estou desenvolvendo com Ionic/AngularJS e SQLite

Tags: angularjs, apache-cordova, sqlite, ionic, netbeans

Estou tentando abrir no SQLiteBrowser o banco de dados, porém não consigo encontrar o arquivo criado.

Utilizei o comando  : window.openDatabase

O alias que dei é "my.db" porém não encontro em lugar algum.

Em que pasta o Ionic/AngularJS cria o banco ?